# How to handle KeyDown in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Ok here's my dilemma. here's this code I have:

```
   If e.KeyCode = Keys.A Then
        TextBox1.AppendText("C, ")
        PictureBox2.Visible = True
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.C, AudioPlayMode.Background)
   End If
```

Now when I enter this under Form1_KeyDown, visual basic thinks this:

'KeyCode is not a a member of 'System.EventArgs'

Now I've seen this code work before, but it isn't here. Any help?

Here's the full code:

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs)
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.A Then
        TextBox1.AppendText("A, ")
        PictureBox2.Visible = True
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.C, AudioPlayMode.Background)
    End If
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.S Then
        TextBox1.AppendText("C,")
        PictureBox14.Visible = True
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.D, AudioPlayMode.Background)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you include the code of the full event handler method (including the Sub declaration)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure why you method definition declares `e` as `EventArgs`, but the fix is simply to make the parameter of type [`KeyEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.aspx). This is because `EventArgs` (naturally) does not contain a property called `KeyCode`, but `KeyEventArgs` does!

Change your event handler method definition to the following:

```
Private Sub foo_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs)
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.A Then
        TextBox1.AppendText("A, ")
        PictureBox2.Visible = True
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.C, AudioPlayMode.Background)
    ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.S Then
        TextBox1.AppendText("C,")
        PictureBox14.Visible = True
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.D, AudioPlayMode.Background)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: And, not least, it is part of the signature of the KeyDown event

Comment: @Fredrik: Yeah, that's the more conceptual way to look at it.

Comment: I suggest you give your controls better names than TextBox1 and PictureBox2 btw.

Comment: @Noldorin, This is just a teazer code, The actual code is much more indepth, I just thought this would be easier for right now.

Comment: @Tony C: That's fair enough. Is your question answered now, though?

Comment: @Noldorin, Kinda. I know how to do it know, however, it still doesn't work. Thanks for the advice though, it will come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your method is using the wrong EventArgs. The Control.KeyDown event sends it as a System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs. So your code should read as

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs)
   // code here
End Sub
```

Comment: Well the system doesn't register it as an error anymore, but now it won't play the sound.

Comment: Unfortuantely VB.Net isn't my strong suit but I would try changing the location parameter from My.Resources.C to the actual path and see if that plays it. I'm assuming My.Resources.C is the location to the file or is it a byte array?

Answer (score 0):

I've found sometimes you need to provide the full object type similar to the below:

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
MsgBox(e.KeyCode.ToString()) 'Message what the keycode
If (e.KeyCode = Keys.A) Then
    MsgBox("e.KeyCode = Keys.A") 'Message that I've found the A
    TextBox1.AppendText("C, ")
    PictureBox2.Visible = True
    My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.C, AudioPlayMode.Background)
End If
```

End Sub

Have you also tried testing this in a textbox on the form similar to the below (textbox in example is named TextBoxKeyTest)?

```
    Private Sub TextBoxKeyTest_KeyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBoxKeyTest.KeyDown
    MsgBox(e.KeyCode.ToString())'Message what the keycode
    If (e.KeyCode = Keys.A) Then
        MsgBox("e.KeyCode = Keys.A")'Message that I've found the A
        TextBox1.AppendText("C, ")
        PictureBox2.Visible = True
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.C, AudioPlayMode.Background)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @Quest4Denali, no I haven't. I'll try it though.

Answer (score 0):

This should work in VB 2010

```
Private Sub cmdWiden_KeyUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyUp
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Up Then Me.Top = Me.Top - 5
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Down Then Me.Top = Me.Top + 5
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Left Then Me.Left = Me.Left - 5
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Right Then Me.Left = Me.Left + 5
End Sub
```